# grub customizer broken after changing grub backround image option

Tags: 12.10, grub2, grubrescue

As you can see from the [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5656901/) I have a dual boot laptop with win7 and Ubuntu 12.10.

The grub broken after messing around with background picture with grub customizer.I didn't proceed to any change after that.